# Transferring from Red to Gold on 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

So is there any way to transfer my Pokemon from the 3DS version of Pokemon Red to the 3DS version of Pokemon Gold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in the original releases, you'll need two systems to trade between first and second generation games. There is no way to just transfer a Pokémon from first generation to second generation without trading something in return.